# Convert the words after a certain keyword to lower case

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to convert all the words after `AS` in a query with shell script:

```
SELECT
first_name AS First_Name,
last_name AS Last_Name,
AGE('1990-10-12') AS Person_Age
FROM table1
```

The output I need is

```
SELECT
first_name AS first_name,
last_name AS last_name,
AGE('1990-10-12') AS person_age
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, you can use [`\L`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Upper_002fLower-case-conversion), an extension to the [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) that converts everything that follows it to lowercase:

```
$ sed -E 's/(AS)(.*)/\1\L\2/' infile
SELECT
first_name AS first_name,
last_name AS last_name,
AGE('1990-10-12') AS person_age
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/AS/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "AS") $(i+1) = tolower($(i+1))} {print}' < infile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
$ cat aswin.sql
SELECT
first_name AS First_Name,
last_name AS Last_Name,
AGE('1990-10-12') AS Person_Age
FROM table1

$ perl -ne ' { s/\bas\b\s+\b(.+?)\b/AS \L\1\E/gi; print } ' aswin.sql
SELECT
first_name AS first_name,
last_name AS last_name,
AGE('1990-10-12') AS person_age
FROM table1
```